# How to access the type inside a std::variant?

Tags: c++, std-variant

I need to build a vector of a class that can have multiple type like this:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include "Field.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    variant <int, float> v;
    vector <variant<Field<int>, Field<string>, Field<float>>> fdList;
    fdList[0].getName();
}
```

And this is header file `Field.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Field
{
public:
    Field();
    Field(string);
    void setName(string);
    string getName();
    bool isPrime();
    void toPrime();
    void toForeign(Field);
    ~Field();

private:
    string FD_Name;
    vector <T> records;
    bool isPrimeK = false;
    string message;
};

template<class T>
string Field<T>::getName()
{
    return FD_Name;
}
```

When I try to access `getName()` function, Visual Studio keeps giving me the following message error:

> E0135 class "std::variant<Field, Fieldstd::string, Field>" has no member "getName"
> C2039 'getName': is not a member of 'std::variant<Field,Fieldstd::string,Field>'

But it works just fine, if I define my vector like this:

```cpp
vector <Field<int>> fdList;
fdList[0].getName();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `fdList[0]` is a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), and has those members.

Answer (score 1):

For any issue about standard library, I recommend you to check document first.
You can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) about how to use `std::variant`.

In short, you cannot access the content in your `std::variant` like that because its type is `std::variant` but not the types you store in it. For your case, I think you may want to check what's inside first by calling `std::variant::index()` method, then get the value by calling `std::get`.

Comment: i get another issue while trying your solution. I can do `get<0>(fdList[0]).getName();` but i can't do `int i = 0;
 get<i>(fdList[i]).getName();`

Comment: @HoàngTháiVương template parameter(what enclosed by <>) should be compile time constant, so it cannot be a variable. Use a switch or if-else chain to check what is inside, and use corresponding int literal (0,1,2) to extract stuff inside

Comment: BTW you may also use ```std::get<Field<int>>``` instead of ```std::get<0>```, which is more intuitive and self-explaining

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method on `variant` doesn't automatically call the method of the active alternative of `variant`. You'll have to `visit` the active alternative and invoke the corresponding handler. In your case, since you want to handle all of the potential active alternatives the same way, you can do:

```
std::visit([](const auto& field) {
  field.getName();
  // ...
}, fdList[0]);
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the `variant` in something like:

```
struct AnyField {
  string getName() const {
    return std::visit([](const auto& field) { return field.getName(); }, v);
  }

  std::variant<Field<int>, Field<string>, Field<float>> v;
};
```

then use them like you wanted to:

```
vector<AnyField> fdList;
fdList[0].getName();
```